# How to fix an error when seeding a table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I've made the following seed to fill in a table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use TCG\Voyager\Models\Menu;
use TCG\Voyager\Models\MenuItem;

class AddChatMenuSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $menu           = Menu::where('name', 'admin')->firstOrFail();
        $client_menu    = Menu::where('name', 'menu')->firstOrFail();
        // Add a tab of our chat
        $user = MenuItem::firstOrNew([
            'menu_id' => $client_menu->id,
            'title'   => __('Chat'),
            'url'     => '/chat',
            'route'   => null,
        ]);
        if (!$user->exists) {
            $user->fill([
                'target'     => '_self',
                'icon_class' => null,
                'color'      => '#000000',
                'parent_id'  => null,
                'order'      => 1,
            ])->save();
        }
    }
}
```

But an error occured when seeding saying this:
[image]

I've tried to run this but it didn't help.

```
apt install php7.2-cli
```

How to correct the error?

P.S. I've tried to google this error but I didn't find anything.

Comment: This is a terminal/console error - it cannot find the "php" command, as it thinks that first letter is something else. The character it identifies is: https://charbase.com/dcf0-unicode-invalid-character 
Try resetting your path in the terminal https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-print-path-variable/ or use absolute path to the php executable.

Comment: Also, if this is copy/pasted from somewhere try "cleaning" the clipboard by pasting the command into a text only program (e.g. notepad on windows) and copy it again from there.

Comment: remove first `p` in `php` part of your command.

Comment: Yes, I misspelled the "p" letter

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. I misspelled the first "p" letter in the command.

Comment: I've written it in Russian language:-)